# Is it possible to create this with Ethereum?

Tags: blockchain, erc-20

I am building a mobile application and I want to create a cryptocurrency around it. My problem is that I am new to crypto and to be honest I am not even sure if it’s possible what I want to do.

To simplify things, let’s say that my app it’s just a button. When the user tap it, it will generate a word. I want to reward the user for pushing that button by giving them a portion of a coin. Also the reward will be valid only if the generated word hasn't come up in previous attempts.

Is this doable using the ethereum network? If yes, can you point me to the right direction where to begin with? If no, are there any  other crypto networks that can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it.

You can create a Mintable / Burnable ERC-20 (Standard Fungible Token), and you can reward users by minting Tokens into their wallets.

Users must first have an Ethereum Wallet.

You can have a look to Open-Zeppelin to easily deploy an erc20.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Adam, it was really helpful

Comment: Just one more question, is there any limitation of how many coin you can create? If not, how it's possible a coin with that mechanism can have a value if the owner can create at any moment as many as he want?

Comment: you're welcome :), no there is no limitation, you can fix a limitation if you want by modifying the contract